# How do I make my automated Client-Server Java networking code output in the correct sequence?

Tags: java, network-programming

Let me start by saying I know this is a lot of code, and so please bear with me. I am working on a project, where I'm porting [Oracle's Knock-Knock client/server](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) example into a US State-Capital example. So instead of KnockKnock jokes, it runs a series of state-capital queries. It runs roughly like this :

> Server: May I have permission to send you a state-capital query?
>
> Client: Ok
>
> Server: Send me a state , so I can send a capital?
>
> Client: Alabama
>
> Server: The capital of Alabama is Hunstville . Want another one (y/n) ?
>
> Client: n

The motivation for doing this project is to later demonstrate some type of fail-safe ability (after I get this to work I want to use Powershell and use that to run the client-server as a single unit).

Back to my code. When I run it  it's giving me the following output, which is not what I'm looking for. It is supposed to be synchronized so that the client and server are working on one state at a time.  Instead, the client-side is jumping ahead of the server side, and it isn't reaching the last state of Wyoming. I tried to add in some synchronization [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852808/in-java-how-much-slower-is-a-write-to-a-file-than-iterating-through-an-array).

[image: mycodeoutput]

I've linked the full code on pastebin

[FixedMessageSequenceClient](http://pastebin.com/G4pHgGWU)

[FixedMessageSequenceServer](http://pastebin.com/438e6G5v)

[FixedMessageSequenceProtocol](http://pastebin.com/HRA3TtC1)

In the code, I am using a simple text log file of integer numbers :

```
1
2
3
4
```

Note: I am utilizing the Apache [ReversedLinesFileReader](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html) library .

I have a suspicion that my error is because of Java IO writing takes too long. I think it may be because of this block of code:

```
for (int i = modlastNum; i < KKJokes.length ; i++){     
    String fromServer = br.readLine();        
    out.println(KKJokes[ i  % KKJokes.length ]);

    if ( (i % 3 )==2){
       try {
        Thread.sleep(11); 
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
    }   


  // fromServer = br.readLine();   System.out.println ( fromServer ); fromServer = br.readLine();   System.out.println ( fromServer ); //    String fromServer3 = br.readLine();      System.out.println ( fromServer3 )  ; System.out.println ( fromServer )  ; 

if(fromServer.equals("inputOfYes")){                  
    while (!(fromServer.equals("nowlogged"))) {
      fromServer = br.readLine();
    }             
}   

 System.out.println ( fromServer )  ; 

 } // end-forLoop starting at Ln. 93
```

And so my hunch is that my automated sending of queries to the `FixedMessageSequenceServer` class (by way of the `FixedMessageSequenceProtocol` class ) is perhaps going too fast, and maybe the IO inside of `FixedMessageSequenceClient` is a bottleneck.

any tips regarding how to debug this or figure out are appreciated, thanks

Comment: Honestly. I wouldn't add **any** bounty to get a problem debugged. It's a waste and debugging is a capability every programmer needs. Consider problems that are hard to debug a chance to improve your skills.

Comment: @Paul - Ok, seems I can't reverse my bounty... I'll aim to figure it out myself then. And put answer here so hopefully a mod can later reverse the bounty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No need for new answers.** Thanks to Paul above, for encouraging me to figure it out on own :

The issue was that, I overlooked the importance of `FixedSequenceMessageProtocol` class

Since the Client is hard-coded to send everything in the large `StateResponses` array, it needed to have a fourth field for "ack" (should ideally be a multidimensional array), which pairs with the Server's sending of "nowlogged"  :

```
StateResponses[] =  { "Permission granted." , "What is Alabama population", "y", "ack",   //00
                               "Permission granted." , "What is Alaska population", "y", "ack",
```

After this, in the `FixedSequenceMessageProtocol` class I added a new constant final variable, to indicate the pending-status  after we log a state position, `SENTPERMISSION2` :

```
private static final int WAITING = 0;
private static final int SENTPERMISSION = 1;
private static final int SENTPERMISSION2 = 2; // ** new line
private static final int SENTCLUE =  3;   
private static final int ANOTHER = 4;
```

Following, I just need to add another case within the nested-if blocks in the `FixedSequenceMessageProtocol` class:

```
  /* etc more code */ {
        if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase(clues[currentPopulationRequest])) {  
            theOutput = answers[currentPopulationRequest] + " Want another? (y/n)";
            currentPopulationRequest++; 
            state = SENTPERMISSION2 ;   //sentpermssion2,  & in sentPermission2 put another
        } else {
            theOutput = "You're supposed to say \"" + 
            clues[currentPopulationRequest]  + 
            "! Try again. Request to send a state population";
            state = SENTPERMISSION;
        }
    } 

    else if (state == SENTPERMISSION2) {
        if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            theOutput = "Status logged";
            state = ANOTHER;
        } else {
            theOutput = "Bye.";       
            state = WAITING;
        }
    }

    else if (state == ANOTHER) {
        if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("ack")) { /* etc more code */
```