# In Java , how much slower is a write to a file, than iterating through an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I realize that writes are slower in general. But I want to know by how much.

I have some code, in server class, that writes to a log file:

```
if (inputLine.equals("y")){
   System.out.println("\nThe input was Yes!\n");
   newPosition++;
   logPosition();
}
```

The problem is that, on the other side in my client class I am running through an array pretty quickly. It is a regular for-loop :

```
for (int i=0; i<KKJokes.length; i++) {
   out.println(KKJokes[i%KKJokes.length]);
}
```

Variable `out` is for the socket (`out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);`).

I want to know a way to slow down the Client sending to the server (via array). So that it can only start outputting again once we finished writing to the log file.

Also if anyone wants to see, [full Client code](http://pastebin.com/i3VQvQAY) & [full Server code](http://pastebin.com/2yTAd2cq).

Comment: You need to provide more context in your question; links to pastebin et al are discouraged. You need to provide all relevant code in your question itself. Please read the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What if I do a java time calculation to compensate? it may be hacky but I will see

Comment: There are many variables at play here. How fast is your disk. do you flush your write to disk before moving on or move on while the write is still in cache.

Comment: @antiduh - ok sure, will do

Comment: Test and measure. Everybody's computer is different. Nobody can answer this for you.

Comment: Trying to make things happen at the same speed so things line up is really, truly doomed to failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't rely on timing for this. You will have to have the server send an acknowledgement of every message, which the client must read before it sends again.

Comment: Ok I think I see this  - , but How can the server send an acknowledgement to client

Comment: isn't readLine method on socket input stream enough for this "aknowledgement"? I mean shouldn't it already block execution flow in client?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker How? `readLine()` isn't interlocked with the peer. There is a socket send buffer at the client which could be any size from 8k upwards.

Comment: @Coffee The same way the client sent to the server.

Comment: @EJP I've seen how reading a stream hangs because of no input, isn't this case the same?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker That's exactly the mechanism I am proposing for the client to use, but the problem here is the client sending too fast, not `readLine()` blocking because there isn't any data.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the server would `accept` in a loop and let the the socket processing be handled in another thread from a thread pool. Then it could "throttle" accepting (=wait a bit when very busy) when to many requests come in.

Also use a real logger. Besides more functionality like rotating logs, they are built for speed too.

Furthermore use a specified character encoding, so not to be surprised if client and server operate with another encoding:

```
new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The client can still send faster than the server can log, until all the socket buffers fill up, but at that point the client will be way ahead of the server.

Comment: @EJP yes, the exact technical or fundamental problem remains. Though System.out.println (with its flush too) is definitely slow and should be get rid of. This should make the response times shorter. And dispatching requests to other threads is a normal solution worth mentioning. Thank for taking the time. It seems the answer _was_ indeed irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Java's Thread.Sleep() function to temporarily pause execution of the running thread. So your code might look something like this,

```
for (int i = 0; i < KKJokes.length; i++ ) {
  out.println(KKJokes[ i  % KKJokes.length ]);
  Thread.sleep(2000); // Time in milliseconds
}
```

[See the docs for more details.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)
Hope this helps.

Comment: ssee comments above, though it's a way to do things .. it is definitely not reliable in long run. we want some kind of synchronization

Comment: @Coffee But that's not the question you asked. As stated, you asked an XY problem. Not this poster's fault. The problem with this answer is that it doesn't answer the question you did ask either.

Comment: @EJP - touche touche , back to drawin board :D

Comment: @Coffee True it is not a good long term solution, the accepted answer is great.