# In Java, how would I re-initialize the for-loops initialization expression?

Tags: java

I have the following for-loop , used in my [State-Capital program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834919/how-do-i-make-my-automated-client-server-java-networking-code-output-in-the-corr):

```
 for (int i = modlastNum; i <  StateResponses.length  ; i++) { 
  /* Code inside */
 }
```

I want to let `i` become 0 , whenever the current `i` would reach the value of 199. I tried using the following method but it doesn't work right :

```
for (int i = modlastNum; i <  StateResponses.length  ; i++) { 
  /* Code inside */
  if ((i % 199) == 0 ) { i = 0;  }
}
```

Instead it turns `i` to 0, then to 1 at the beginning of the for-loops inner code.

Comment: try setting i to -1.

Comment: When you hit your if statement at 199, it'll set i to 0 then in the next iteration it'll be incremented by the i++. Do what Ray suggested and set it to -1; then when the iteration processes it'll be 0, as you wanted.

Comment: The loop will never complete if `StateResponses.length > 199`.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do and why. Please include some more code.

Comment: Instead of resetting `i`, use the value `0` (if you just want element 200 to be the same as the first element).

Comment: Logically, you have two nested loops, the inner loop you show and an outer loop that runs it with start value modLastNum on the first iteration, 0 on the second and subsequent iterations. Why not code it that way, rather than squeezing it into one loop?

Answer (score 1):

have you thought of using break or maybe setting i =-1... If you aren't using the loop after setting i =0 then call break at the end of call inside if

Comment: I tried to use break... but break would kick me out the whole for-loop . continue skips

Answer (score 1):

`i` will be incremented after every block execution, ie `0` will become `1`. What if you try to apply the next change

```
if ((i % 199) == 0 ) { i = -1;}
```

However it would be great to know what goal are you trying to achieve here, because above code is not easy to understand.

Comment: sure, this is used in the code for my prev. question - it automatically sends state-capital queries/answers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834919/how-do-i-make-my-automated-client-server-java-networking-code-output-in-the-corr

Comment: Sorry, I missed your statement on the top of the question. I would consider using `while (some_clause)` loop instead of for loop in this case, this should make code clearer and if you still need a counter, just initialise it before while loop and increment/set to 0 inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set i to -1.

Look at for loop syntax first. The for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    //code here
}
```

means

```
int i = 0;
while (i < value) {
    //code here
    i++
}
```

So, at the end of your code, i is incremented by one. You need to set i = -1 in order for i to be equal to 0 on the next iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to incorporate the update in the for loop description - there's a whole section for exactly that, remember. The format is

```
for ( <initialisation> ; <termination condition> ; <increment> ) {
    body
}
```

What you're talking about is actually updating the loop variable so it should go in the `increment` section of the for statement. A bit like this...

```
for (int i = modlastNum; 
     i <  StateResponses.length  ;
     i = (i % 199) == 0 ?  0 : i + 1) {
    <loop body>
}
```

You can do something similar in the loop body by setting `i` to `-1` rather than `0` but ideally you should avoid updating the loop counter within the body itself if you're using this style of `for`.